# How to avoid or restrict PHP Error output

Tags: php, error-handling

My PHP web-app sometimes returns this `Fatal error on Line XXX` due to reasons like extremely-slow-connection speed. Although, this  occurs rarely, like 1 in 1000 times, I want to avoid such output on the browser. I am doing error logging on server side for some functions. So, I don't want to completely disable error reporting. Just that I don't want to display it to the end user.

Comment: you can add `@` in the process , It suppresses error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable any error display to the user of your page, set

```
display_errors = Off
```

in your php.ini (this is the recommended setting for production websites anyway!) or

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

in your php.

This `display_errors` setting only affects the output on the webpage; it will not affect a possibly configured logfile; there the messages still would be logged.

See the php documentation on configuring error reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

**Note:** The `error_reporting` setting mentioned by other users here, will, to my knowledge, affect all kinds of error reports (i.e. also what is reported to a possibly configured log file). If you set `error_reporting` to 0, you won't get any log entries as well. If you want to log something to the log file but not show it to the user, the `display_errors` setting is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

**Various Examples on turning off error_reporting..**

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

*note : You can put or `include()` it in any file you dont want to explicit errors. Or if you want to totally off it. Go with tweaks in php.ini file.*

Lines to find in your php.ini to tweaks  and off error_reporting.

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); //change to Off
        error_reporting(E_ALL); // change to 0
```

FOR FURTHER INFO :: [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks. That's useful. But ini_set('display_errors', 0); did the trick for me here.

Comment: @Kaii btw...if I do error_reporting(0); and then try to do error_log('some msg'), will it work?

Comment: @nyarlathotep thanks. I got that solution from other stackoverflow question. My points are low so cannot upvote any answer for now :(

Comment: @emotionull that's ok, you could still accept it ;) actually before quickly posting my answer I wanted to search for duplicates because I'm sure this was asked before, but on a quick search actually didn't find anything exactly related;) for your error_reporting question, see my updated answer (in a few sseconds

Comment: @emotional `log_errors = off` will just do the tricks with that.

Comment: @Kaii you have it the wrong way around I think. OP wants to *log* errors, but not display them to the user. `log_errors=off` will disable logging! also `error_reporting is not really a good way to go (see my post). The `display_errors` line is the only good hint in your answer, but it's hidden among too many unnecessary error_reporting references...

Answer (score 1):

on the start of that page write

```
  error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: that will disable any reporting of errors (also in the logfile)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues like this you can set the **max_execution_time=1024M** to avoid slow speed data generation and to hide errors is must likely error_reporting=0 on the php.ini file.

Or simply:

```
PHP Code
ini_set('max_execution_time',1024M);
error_reporting(0);

PHP Ini Settings
max_execution_time=1024M
error_reporting=0
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(0); only works if you are not using set_error_handler('my_function'). If this is your case, you have suppress the error message in 'my_function'.